# C# VS2010 How to force setup project to install application without asking for user input

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installation, auto-update

Is there a way to tell "Setup Project" in Visual Studio 2010 to force installation of an application without asking for any kind of user input, like "destination directory", "finish" and "next" buttons, etc.

I would just like the user (or another program) to run "setup.exe" and the application would be installed. Without prompting or asking for information.

I think FileZilla Client has a feature like the one I just described. But then again they have a custom setup project...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [silent installation feature](http://unattended.sourceforge.net/installers.php) of Windows Installer.

Comment: Love it! I used the following: "msiexec /i YOURPACKAGE.msi /qn" Thank you, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using a ClickOnce deployment instead.  It provides the ability to auto-update the app from a UNC location, ftp server, CD/DVD, etc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx